# Prevent inbox.google.com from bundling Github emails

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

Is there any way to prevent Inbox from always bundling Github emails? I may have just overlooked a setting somewhere...

It's very annoying when you only have a single email that gets bundled unnecessarily.

[image]

Comment: Actually this is not what they call bundling, but anyway, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible without any external modification. I was also annoyed by this behavior!

Comment: Hey! :-) thanks for your comment! What's it called if not a bundle? And what do you mean by external modification? Can you outline how? Thanks!

Comment: From what I understand, Inbox bundle is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VVQT.png) which opens to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD2bD.png). And the annoying situation as you showed is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKcan.png) is something else (maybe actually also called bundle, but it's not the bundle they refer to in the settings). In the options of each label, there's the possibility to `bundle` it, which converts from what you see to the first imaged I linked (assuming you have a label for GitHub).

Comment: About the modification - I haven't tried, but maybe it's possible to change the html (with a user script) and remove the divs that create this "bundle", so it will look like a regular email. I noticed that for example for emails from my family it's not getting bundled or under a category - so it can be compared to such email.

Comment: I really hope for a solution for that 

Comment: Thanks! So let's just submit as much as feedback as we can: Menu > Help & Feedback > Send Feedback

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.